# Looking for VIA ChromotionHD 2.0 driver

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, via

I'm a newbe on the Linux front. Installed a new copy of `lubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64` on a `HP T5570 Thin Client` (put in a 64 GB SSD for installation) for testing purpose.

Install is fine but the screen only shows at a 640x480 resolution.
Inside the 5570 there is a VIA `ChromotionHD` 2.0 videochip.
Anyboby here that knows if there are drivers for installation to get better screen resolution?
Or maybe has another option?

I would prefer a `1280x720` screen resolution at the least.
Even a new install of an older Lubuntu (or other) version is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, you will need to manually install OpenChrome DDX package.

$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-hwe-16.04

Please note that the default version you will get with Lubuntu 16.04.2 might be Version 0.3.3.
I recommend installing the latest code from the OpenChrome DDX repository (Version 0.6.xxx).
This post I made while back covered how to install the latest code.

https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/openchrome-users/2016-February/007237.html

Please make sure to substitute "xserver-xorg-video-openchrome" of the above page with "xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-hwe-16.04' or it will wreck your existing installation.
You can ask questions about installation here.

https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/openchrome-users

Regards,

Kevin Brace

The OpenChrome Project maintainer / developer